# python simple password login with limited trial with while loop

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, while-loop, passwords

```
Z=1     #username can be ramdom as long as password is cyber
while (Z>0):
    Z=Z+1
    username=raw_input('key in your username: ')
    if username==(""):
        print '\nPlease do not leave it blank! \nPlease type again... \n'
    else:
        Z=0
else:
    Z=Z+1
P=0 #password part
while (P<3):
    pssw=raw_input('key in your password: ')
    if pssw=="cyber":
        P=3
    else:
        pssw=raw_input('\nWrong password, \nSecond chance: ')
        P=P+1
        if pssw=="cyber":
            P=3
        else:
            pssw=raw_input('\nWrong password, \nWrong again will terminate the program... \nType again: ')
            P=P+1
            if pssw=="cyber":
                P=3
            else:
                print "Bye..."
                exit('ASGN_1151102784_A01A.py')     #terminate program after 3 error pssw
print "\nWelcome "+username
#to be continue...
```

above is my login code, which require any random username but with the condition that password must be cyber only. However, my lecturer refuse to accept this code as she says that the password checking system shall be done within the while loop instead of creating new if else statement inside the while loop.

Now i'm really confused. Is there any solution for requesting a password from user with 3 trial and if password correct then continue to run the program else exit the program with just simple while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this:

```
...
P=0 #password part
pssw = None
messages = {
    0: 'key in your password: ',
    1: '\nWrong password, \nSecond chance: ',
    2: '\nWrong password, \nWrong again will terminate the program... \nType again: '
}
try:
    while (pssw != 'cyber'):
        pssw=raw_input(messages[P])
        P += 1
except KeyError:
    print "Bye..."
    exit('ASGN_1151102784_A01A.py')     #terminate program after 3 error pssw
else:
    print "\nWelcome "+username
```